# Fail to position 1 section on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, resize

I have an website that auto resize to mobile version but I am having trouble with resize 1 section to mobile version, I want to the Place, Country, Phone Number, Adress, Email to be on the left of the screen but none of the things I tried really worked.

```css
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind); /*--- Body Font --*/
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita); /*--- Heading Font --*/
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial);
  * {
   margin : 0;
   padding : 0;
   border : 0;
  }

  body {
   background-color :#dbdbdb;
   font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
   font-size :18px ;
   position : relative;
  }
  h1 {
   font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color : #4A4444;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top : 150px;
  }
  h4 {
   color : #4A4444;
   font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  }

  p {
   padding : 2%;
   color : #4A4444;
   text-align:justify;
   max-width: 100%;
  }

  img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: : auto;
  }
  #banner-wrapper{
   max-width: 1280px;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  .sidebar{
   border: 1px solid;
   width:26%;
   float : left;
   margin:4% 4%;
  }
  #map {
          width: 100%;
          height: 350px;
          min-height: :350px;
        }


  .right-col{
   width:60%;
   float: right;
   margin:4% 0 4% 4%;
   background-color: #dbdbdb;
  }
  .clear {
   clear : both;
  }
  footer {
   width: 100%;
   height:60px;
   background-color :#e5e5e6;
   margin :0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: auto;
      border-top: 0.1px solid #6ca204
  }
  footer p {
   text-align: center;
   color : #4A4444;
   padding :15px;
  }

   #hline {
    visibility: visible;
   }

  @keyframes slider {
   
   0% {
    left: 0%;
   }
   
   20% {
    left: 0%;
   }
   
   25% {
    left: -100%;
   }
   
   45% {
    left: -100%;
   }
   
   50% {
    left: -200%;
   }
   
   70% {
    left: -200%;
   }
   
   75% {
    left: -300%;
   }
   
   95% {
    left: -300%;
   }
   
  }
  #slider {
   overflow: hidden;
   width:100%;
  }
  #slider figure img {
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
  }
  #slider figure {
   position: relative;
   width : 500%;
   margin: 0;
   left: 0;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 0;
   animation : 20s slider infinite;
  }

  label {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
   color : #000;
   font-size :130% ;
      font-weight: bold;

  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="banner-wrapper">
  <h1>Contacts</h1>
  <section class="right-col">
  <label class="place">Place:</label><h4 class="h4place">sdffadfdf</h4>
  <label class="country">Country:</label><h4 class="h4country">sdffadfdf</h4>
  <label class="pnumber">Phone Number:</label><h4 class id="h4pnumber">sdffadfdf</h4>
  <label class="adress">Adress:</label><h4 class ="h4adress">sdffadfdf</h4>
  <label class="email">Email:</label><h4 class="h4email">sdffadfdf</h4>
  </section>
 <section class ="sidebar">
   <div id="map"></div>
     <script>
       function initMap() {
         var uluru = {lat:38.755181, lng:-9.142975};
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
           zoom: 15,
           center: uluru
         });
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: uluru,
           map: map
         });
       }
     </script>
     <script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCZ02PzAtIujMucF_Deulpvwo0FD4LWLtw&callback=initMap">
     </script>
  </section>
  <div id="hline" style="width: 100%;height:2px;background-color: #4a4444;z-index: 5;overflow: auto; opacity: 1;">
 </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer>
   <p>&copy; HardSecure 2017-2017</p>
  </footer>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

mobile version

```css
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind); /*--- Body Font --*/
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita); /*--- Heading Font --*/
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial);
  * {
   margin : 0;
   padding : 0;
   border : 0;
  }

  body {
   background-color :#dbdbdb;
   font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
   font-size :18px ;
   position : relative;
  }
  h1 {
   font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color : #4A4444;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top : 150px;
  }
  h4 {
   color : #4A4444;
   font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  }

  p {
   padding : 2%;
   color : #4A4444;
   text-align:justify;
   max-width: 100%;
  }

  img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: : auto;
  }
  #banner-wrapper{
   max-width: 1280px;
   margin:0 auto;
  }
  .sidebar{
   border: 1px solid;
   width:26%;
   float : left;
   margin:4% 4%;
  }
  #map {
          width: 100%;
          height: 350px;
          min-height: :350px;
        }


  .right-col{
   width:60%;
   float: right;
   margin:4% 0 4% 4%;
   background-color: #dbdbdb;
  }
  .clear {
   clear : both;
  }
  footer {
   width: 100%;
   height:60px;
   background-color :#e5e5e6;
   margin :0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: auto;
      border-top: 0.1px solid #6ca204
  }
  footer p {
   text-align: center;
   color : #4A4444;
   padding :15px;
  }

   #hline {
    visibility: visible;
   }

  @keyframes slider {
   
   0% {
    left: 0%;
   }
   
   20% {
    left: 0%;
   }
   
   25% {
    left: -100%;
   }
   
   45% {
    left: -100%;
   }
   
   50% {
    left: -200%;
   }
   
   70% {
    left: -200%;
   }
   
   75% {
    left: -300%;
   }
   
   95% {
    left: -300%;
   }
   
  }
  #slider {
   overflow: hidden;
   width:100%;
  }
  #slider figure img {
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
  }
  #slider figure {
   position: relative;
   width : 500%;
   margin: 0;
   left: 0;
   text-align: left;
   font-size: 0;
   animation : 20s slider infinite;
  }

  label {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
   color : #000;
   font-size :130% ;
      font-weight: bold;

  }

   @media screen and (max-width: 481px){
   .sidebar, #map {
    width: 100%;
    margin :0;
          height: 300px;
   }
   .right-col {
    width: : 100%;
    margin: 0 0 3% 0;
    text-align :left;
   }
  }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="banner-wrapper">
  <h1>Contacts</h1>
  <section class="right-col">
  <label class="place">Place:</label><h4 class="h4place">sdffadfdf</h4>
  <label class="country">Country:</label><h4 class="h4country">sdffadfdf</h4>
  <label class="pnumber">Phone Number:</label><h4 class id="h4pnumber">sdffadfdf</h4>
  <label class="adress">Adress:</label><h4 class ="h4adress">sdffadfdf</h4>
  <label class="email">Email:</label><h4 class="h4email">sdffadfdf</h4>
  </section>
 <section class ="sidebar">
   <div id="map"></div>
     <script>
       function initMap() {
         var uluru = {lat:38.755181, lng:-9.142975};
         var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
           zoom: 15,
           center: uluru
         });
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: uluru,
           map: map
         });
       }
     </script>
     <script async defer
     src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCZ02PzAtIujMucF_Deulpvwo0FD4LWLtw&callback=initMap">
     </script>
  </section>
  <div id="hline" style="width: 100%;height:2px;background-color: #4a4444;z-index: 5;overflow: auto; opacity: 1;">
 </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <footer>
   <p>&copy; HardSecure 2017-2017</p>
  </footer>
  <div class="clear"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

mobile css

Comment: Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve] WITHOUT the PHP. Just the view-source from the browser since there is no PHP issue here

Comment: @mplungjan done

Comment: Change main-wrapper float to right, and place the .sidebar tags before #banner-wrapper